# Excel VBA help - run a series of regex find and replaces

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has become very complex. On it, there is a sheet in which a user will paste data about once every other day. The data will always be in the same format, and is provided to us in an exact way only. Once pasted in, I need a way for a very average user of excel to be able to press a button (or key combo, or whatever) and excel will run a series of about 8-10 regex find and replaces. All of these will be on column A of the data. Once those are all run, a simple formula would be run on every cell C2 and below in column C. Those columns should be reduced by 80% - =C2*.8

This should all be done with minimal user input if possible.

Would anybody much more versed in regex or excel know a better direction for me to look for a proper start? What resources would be recommended to best accomplish this?

Comment: while you can use regex in excel, it might be simpler not to. could you provide an example of your source data (or the structure) and more info on what data you need to extract and use?

Comment: +1 to the comment above. We need to see your data (ideally in a sample workbook).

Answer (score 0):

If you're multiplying by some factor, then regexp substitution will be overkill. Excel is very good at multiplying an array of numbers by 0.8.

Search for "Excel paste factor" and you'll get an easy explanation, such as [this one](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=78512).

I might record a macro for your less-experienced users and hope that the previous user pasted the numbers in with absolute perfection.

Comment: the multiplication part is simple, the more important are the 8-10 consecutive regex find and replaces on column A first.

Comment: would you be able to post some of the transformations in your question?

Comment: the only one I seem to be having trouble with right now is matching only "-3" at the end of the cell only - regex should be simply "-3$" - replaced with "" (absolutely nothing)

Comment: without more detail we cant really help any further. -3 is meaningless